# SSL connection not trust

Tags: ssl, tls

I am new to SSL/TLS and i have a certificate issue: testing connection between client and server(payara server) is ok, "client hello" . back way is refused :

```
handshake_failure javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

so i assume that the DigiCert Global Root CA must be trusted and in the trust store in payara , so how can i import a certificate.pem to the trust store in payara?

Comment: [check the documentation](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.201/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/ssl-certificates.html)

Comment: Also, verify the client and server have the correct time and date (update both via a well-known NTP server, such as `time.nist.gov`)